# Prettier doesn't format angular templates on vscode

Tags: javascript, angular, visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm using VSCode with prettier installed, and when I try to format angular html templates, it doesn't work, and in the output tab I see:

> Identifier expected. (c:\dev\prospera-herolo\src\app\table\components\pivot-> > filter\pivot-filter.component.html:1:27)
>
> 1 | < div class="pivot-filter" (clickOutside)="closeFilter()">

How can I format angular template?

Comment: what about beautify?

Comment: You seem to have a space between the opening `<` tag and `div`, might that be the issue?